# горизонтальный scrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, прокрутка, scrollview

У меня есть горизонтальный `scrollView`. 0 - это стартовый экран. Хочу задать ограничения кнопкам. `next` должна листать вправо от 0 до 5. `back` должна листать влево от 5 до 0 (не -1). Как это сделать?

```
-(IBAction)next:(id)sender
{
    self.currentPage++;
    CGFloat pageWidth = scroll.frame.size.width;
    [scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(pageWidth*self.currentPage, 0) animated:YES];
}

-(IBAction)back:(id)sender
{
    self.currentPage--;
    CGFloat pageWidth = scroll.frame.size.width;
    [scroll setContentOffset:CGPointMake(pageWidth*self.currentPage, 0) animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

в `next:` первой строкой дописать

```
if(self.currentPage == 5) return;  // или 4, если у вас 5 экранов всего
```

в `back:`

```
if(self.currentPage == 0) return;
```

чтобы просто игнорировать нажатия.

Comment: Спасибо! Это работает. Но есть проблема. Если я листаю с помощью кнопок,  а потом использую жесты, то кнопки перестают работать или ведут себя странно(листают на несколько экранов вперед или вообще не листают) Как можно синхронизировать жесты с кнопками?

Comment: происходит это из за того, что при свайпе ваш `currentPage` не изменяется. можете либо отключить userInteraction и заставить пользователя использовать кнопки, либо избавиться от currentPage и высчитывать оффсет динамически

Answer (score 1):

Перед сдвигом проверяй scroll.contentOffset.x. Он не должен быть меньше 0 и больше pageWidth*4.

В идеале после каждого сдвига проверяешь scroll.contentOffset.x. Если он == 0, то деактивируешь кнопку back. Аналогично для кнопки next.